# Using a vector of characters in C++ to program a Caesar Cipher

Tags: c++, encryption

I've been working a piece of code to encrypt a message using the Caesar Cipher. I've tried to keep it simple.

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: Skylar Croy
 *
 * Created on February 10, 2015, 11:50 AM
 * 
 * Purpose: To encrypt a message using the Caesar Cipher 
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char letters[] = 
    {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}; // Make a vector, letter, which equals [a b c ... z]
    int i, k; // i used in two loops, k used for shift 3 and mod calc

    for (i=0; i<=25; i++) { // Run 26 times (1 for each letter)

        k = (i + 3) % 26; // Performs mod arth. with shift of 3

        letters[i+26] = letters[k]; // letter[i+26] = [d e f g ... c]
        // Note that letters = [a b c ... z d e f g....c]
             /* cout << letters[i]; // This code shows that the operation in this for loop is functioning correctly
                cout << " ";
                cout << letters[i+26];
                cout << " \n"; */          
    }

    std:: string x; // declare string x
    cin >> x; 

        int string_length = x.size();

    for (i=0; i<=(string_length-1); i++){ // individual characters of string x can be referenced by x[0] etc

        for (k=0; k<=25; k++){ 

            if (x[i] == letters[k]) {

                            cout << letters[k+26];

            }
        }
    } 
return 0;
}
```

For some reason when you try to encrypt a message with a w, x, y, or z it doesn't work and prints random trash. Not sure what is wrong. Any advice would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need an array of all letters when most modern computer platforms use ASCII coding? And when most of the other character coding schemes put a-z together in order?

Comment: [Related](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/12257/489).

Comment: `letters[i+26] = letters[k]`. What is the size of `letters`? What are the bounds on `i`? Ask those questions and you have your answer.

Comment: The heart of the Caesar Cipher is the `modulo` arithmetic.  Read up on it.  Pretend that your array of letters is a circular array of letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't finished reading your code but the following line is definitely going out of bounds:

```
letters[i+26] = letters[k]; // letter[i+26] = [d e f g ... c]
```

Your `letters` array is only 26 long and yet you're accessing `i+26`-th element. Maybe try:

```
letters[(i+26)%26] = letters[k]; // letter[i+26] = [d e f g ... c]
```

You definitely should **NOT** try to assign values out of bounds of your array!

Similarly, when you are printing your letters in:

```
cout << letters[k+26];
```

You are going **out of bounds** of your array which means that you will be printing garbage...

This is probably not all that is wrong but it is a start...

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have pointed out the error in your original attempt. I just want to say your goal can be achieved within two lines:

```
for (auto& each : x)    // where x is your std::string
    each = (each - 'a' + 3) % 26 + 'a';
```

Comment: I tried something like this in my code and I think it helped clean it up a lot. When I went back and reviewed ASCII characters it made much more sense to use this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One more hint (besides mentioned above writing beyond array) - you can't just do substitution like that:

`letters[i] = letters[k];`

because you would overwrite existing items. Maybe simpler and better option is to use another array to create modified alphabet?

`char new_letters = new char[26];
for (int i=0; i<26; i++)
   new_letters[i] = letters[(i+3) % 26];`

and use the new array for encoding by:

`if ('a' - x[i] < 26)
   cout << new_letters['a'-x[i]];`

which will substitute only small letters

Answer (score 0):

@nonsensickle was correct. Simply making another vector of length 26 for the encrypted vector fixed it. Thanks!

The code below works:

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: Skylar Croy
 *
 * Created on February 10, 2015, 11:50 AM
 * 
 * Purpose: To encrypt a message using the Caesar Cipher 
 */

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char letters[] = 
    {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'}; // Make a vector, letter, which equals [a b c ... z]
    int i, k; // i used in two loops, k used for shift 3 and mod calc
    char letters_cipher[25];

    for (i=0; i<=25; i++) { // Run 26 times (1 for each letter)

        k = (i + 3) % 26; // Performs mod arth. with shift of 3

        letters_cipher[i] = letters[k]; // letter[i+26] = [d e f g ... c]
        // Note that letters = [a b c ... z d e f g....c]
        /*
        cout << letters[i]; // This code shows that the operation in this for loop is functioning correctly
        cout << " ";
        cout << letters[i+26];
        cout << " \n";
        */          
    }

    std:: string x; // declare string x
    cin >> x; 

    int string_length = x.size();

    for (i=0; i<=(string_length-1); i++){ // individual characters of string x can be referenced by x[0] etc
        for (k=0; k<=25; k++){ 
            if (x[i] == letters[k]) {
                cout << letters_cipher[k];
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your new vector is of size `25` which I think should be `26`. If you have a vector defined as `char letters_cipher[25]` then you can only use indices between `0` and `24`... Possibly just a typo.